# append rsyslog PID in template filename

Tags: rsyslog

I have a template in my rsyslog and what i wish to do is add the process id of rsyslog to the end of the generated file. Note here that i need the pid of rsyslog server not the pid of the process generating the message.

My template :

```
$template FULL_FQDN,"/logs/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%_<pid_here>.log"
```

Is there any way to achieve this in rsyslog?
I am running rsyslog 8.24